# Spring Cloud Vault Configuration without YAML file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have mentioned the Spring Cloud Vault Configuration in my `bootstrap.yml`file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: *****
        secret-id: ****
      host: ****
      port: 80
      scheme: http
```

But i dont want to have these in my YML file, rather i would like to have these configured as a bean

> @configuration / @bean

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this successfully by configuring a `Bean` of type `VaultProperties`. Below is the code snippet which completely eliminated the need for maintaining the same in `bootstrap.yml`

```
@Configuration
public class VaultConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public VaultProperties vaultProperties() {

        VaultProperties vaultProperties = new VaultProperties();

        vaultProperties.setAuthentication(VaultProperties.AuthenticationMethod.APPROLE);

        VaultProperties.AppRoleProperties appRoleProperties = new VaultProperties.AppRoleProperties();
        appRoleProperties.setRoleId("****");
        appRoleProperties.setSecretId("****");

        vaultProperties.setAppRole(appRoleProperties);
        vaultProperties.setHost("***");
        vaultProperties.setPort(80);
        vaultProperties.setScheme("http");

        return vaultProperties;
    }
}
```

Note : When you are having a configuration  that should be treated as bootstrap-configuration, then you need to mention the class name under `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

The content in `spring.factories` is

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=com.arun.local.cloudconfig.VaultConfiguration
```